# Multiplying IEEE-754 Floating point number in MIPS

Tags: mips

I have to multiply a floating point number (with IEEE 754 format) by 2 without using floating point instructions.

What I am having trouble with is fixing the exponent part after the multiplication.

This is what I have.

Assume the *single* precision floating point number is in register **$t0**

```
sll    $t1, $t0, 9        t1 holds fraction part
sll    $t2, $t0, 1
srl    $t2, $t2, 24       t2 holds exponent part
srl    $t3, $t0, 31       t3 holds the sign bit

sll    $t1, $t1, 1        multiply fraction by 2
#do something to exponent in $t2 ##

#now put it all back together
sll    $t3, $t3, 31       put sign bit in the 31nd bit position
sll    $t2, $t2, 23       put exponent in the 30-23 bit positions
srl    $t1, $t1, 9        put fraction in the 22-0 bit positions

or     $t4, $t1, $t2
or     $t4, $t4, $t3      t4 now holds the value of t0*2
```

I dont understand how the exponent would change if I multiplied the fraction by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the wrong thing here

```
sll    $t1, $t1, 1        multiply fraction by 2
```

IEEE-754 floating point number's value is based on this formula

> (-1)<sup>sign</sup> × 1.mantissa × 2<sup>exponent</sup>

When multiply by 2, only the radix point is moved to the right, all the bits remain unchanged, so the mantissa part is the same as before (unless the exponent overflows or the value is not normal). To multiply by 2, you increase the exponent by 1, not multiply it by 2 because **2 × 2<sup>exp</sup> = 2<sup>exp+1</sup>**

So you should do like this

```
addi $t2, $t2, 1
```

Comment: so if I want to multiply $t0 by 2 I just need to extract exponent bits and add one to it? 

then append new exponent back into $t0 ?

Comment: correct. Adding 1 naively to that result in wrong result